# How to print abc into zyx (mirror values in alpha) in java

Tags: java, string

how to print mirror value of alphabet in java?

```
public class Alphamirror {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String s1=sc.next();
        String s2="";
        char c;
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<s1.length();i++)
            if(s1.charAt(i)<'m')
                s2=s1.charAt(i)+
            else if(||s1.charAt(i)>'z')
    }
```

Comment: OP, you have a history of not following up on your questions. You do not respond to comments and you do neither accept nor comment on offered answers. SO is a network that also depends on feedback to assess the quality and applicability of the offered answers. Please follow up and accept/upvote answers in the future. People used their spare time to help you; at least show some courtesy to acknowledge this. It is just a simple mouse-click.

Answer (score 2):

you can figure out index of mirror alphabet and print that. see the below code..

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
   {
    // your code goes here
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    String s1=sc.next();

    for(int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
        int index = 'z' - s1.charAt(i);
        System.out.print((char)('a' + index));  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function that will mirror letters like the following:

```
static char alphaMirror(char c) {
    int maxAdvance = 25;

    int diff = c - ((c > 'Z') ? 'a' : 'A');

    int advance = maxAdvance - 2 * diff;

    return (char) (c + advance);
}
```

You can then call it, e.g, from main like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    String s2 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        System.out.println(i + ": " + alphaMirror(s.charAt(i)));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        System.out.println(i + ": " + alphaMirror(s2.charAt(i)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
public class Temp {

    public static Map<Character, Character> prepareMirrorMap() {
        Map<Character, Character> charMap = new HashMap<>();
        charMap.put(Character.valueOf('A'), Character.valueOf('Z'));
        charMap.put(Character.valueOf('B'), Character.valueOf('Y'));
        charMap.put(Character.valueOf('C'), Character.valueOf('X'));
        charMap.put(Character.valueOf('D'), Character.valueOf('W'));
        return charMap;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String temp = "ABCD";
        System.out.println(ConvertToMirrorString.convertToMirror(temp));
    }
}

class ConvertToMirrorString {
    private static Map<Character, Character> charMap;

    static {
        charMap = Temp.prepareMirrorMap();
    }

    public static String convertToMirror(String inputString) {
        StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
        for (Character c : inputString.toCharArray()) {
            temp.append(charMap.get(c));
        }
        return temp.toString();
    }
}
```

This is a working piece of code, however you need to add more data for map.